# Linking two CheckedListBoxes to populate one based off the other

Tags: c#, user-controls, checklistbox

I am trying to link two `checkedListboxes` so that when you check an item on the first (which is a list of types), it will then populate the second with a list of categories within that type. This will all be done using Oracle statement.

So far I have this set up:

[image]

Now I am trying to get it so that the UserControl has a controller which takes in:

```
TypeCategorySelectorController(typeselector, categoryselector, reportdata)
```

The problem is I do not know how to use this class properly to link the two checklistboxes?
It currently has access to all the methods/properties needed.

Does anyone know if this is the right way to do it? if so what am I missing?